# loading csv file using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my sample data:

```
2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00,,"42,00,00,00,3E,51,1B,D7,42,1C,00,00,40"
2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00,,"42,00,00,00,3E,51,1B,D7,42,1C,00,00,40"
2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00,,"42,00,00,00,3E,51,1B,D7,42,1C,00,00,40"
```

I tried to load the data using pandas using :

```
data = pd.read_csv("sample.csv",header = None)
```

My output is:

```
                0                 1           2
0  2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00 NaN  42,00,00,00,3E,51,1B,D7,42,1C,00,00,40
1  2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00 NaN  42,00,00,00,3E,51,1B,D7,42,1C,00,00,40
2  2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00 NaN  42,00,00,00,3E,51,1B,D7,42,1C,00,00,40
```

I wanted to separate each data in second column with first column as time stamp.

My expected output would be:

```
    0                             1  2  3  4....
0  2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00  42 00 00 00
1  2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00  42 00 00 00
2  2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00  42 00 00 00
```

Comment: So whats the expected output?

Comment: @Dark sorry for the confusion! I have updated the question again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, if needed, do your own csv parser like:

#### Code:

```
def read_my_csv(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rU') as f:

        # build csv reader
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        # for each row, check for footer
        for row in reader:
            yield [row[0]] + row[2].split(',')
```

#### Test Code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(read_my_csv('csvfile.csv'))
print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
                                  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  \
0      2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00  42  00  00  00  3E  51  1B  D7  42  1C   
1      2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00  42  00  00  00  3E  51  1B  D7  42  1C   
2      2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00  42  00  00  00  3E  51  1B  D7  42  1C   

   11  12  13  
0  00  00  40  
1  00  00  40  
2  00  00  40
```

Comment: Nice but isn’t it possible to move the with open to inside the function?

Answer (score 3):

Pass a `sep` argument with a regular expression. Afterwards, do a little cleanup on the data.

```
df = pd.read_csv(
      'file.csv', 
      sep='"*,',           # separator
      header=None,         # no headers
      engine='python',     # allows a regex with multiple characters
      index_col=[0]        # specify timestamp as the index
)   

df.iloc[:, 1] = df.iloc[:, 1].str.strip('"').astype(int)
df.iloc[:, -1] = df.iloc[:, -1].str.strip('"').astype(int)
```

```
df

                               1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  \
0                                                                               
2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00 NaN  42   0   0   0  3E  51  1B  D7  42  1C   0   
2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00 NaN  42   0   0   0  3E  51  1B  D7  42  1C   0   
2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00 NaN  42   0   0   0  3E  51  1B  D7  42  1C   0   

                               13  14  
0                                      
2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00   0  40  
2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00   0  40  
2017-11-27T00:29:37.698-06:00   0  40
```

To drop the column with NaNs, use `dropna` -

```
df.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Downvoter, if there's something wrong with this answer, please let to know, so it canbe  correct. Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks, I just wanted to confirm. I guess it's the same user who has been mass downvoting my answers. They've downvoted 4 of my answers so far. I believe the moderators should be able to handle it from there. They'll record the user's misconduct.

Comment: I have same experience, but the best is one comment in META about it - dont panic. I have no reason for do it.

Comment: Unfortunately I think this should be some angry user(s) :(

Answer (score 3):

First add parameter `parse_dates=[0]` for parse first column to datetime.

Then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)ed column `2` and remove columns `1` and `2`, last `rename` all columns with add `1`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv",header = None, parse_dates=[0])

df = (df.drop([1,2], axis=1)
        .join(df[2].str.split(',', expand=True)
        .rename(columns = lambda x: x+1))   
      )  
print (df)
                       0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13
0 2017-11-27 06:29:37.698  42  00  00  00  3E  51  1B  D7  42  1C  00  00  40
1 2017-11-27 06:29:37.698  42  00  00  00  3E  51  1B  D7  42  1C  00  00  40
2 2017-11-27 06:29:37.698  42  00  00  00  3E  51  1B  D7  42  1C  00  00  40
```

**Detail**

```
print (df[2].str.split(',', expand=True))
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
0  42  00  00  00  3E  51  1B  D7  42  1C  00  00  40
1  42  00  00  00  3E  51  1B  D7  42  1C  00  00  40
2  42  00  00  00  3E  51  1B  D7  42  1C  00  00  40
```

Comment: Seems like my answer has been downvoted. You see anything wrong with it?

Comment: Not me, I dont know...Your answer is OK, no reason.